# Why is my ArrayList not initialized to the capacity i specify?

Tags: java, arraylist

I keep getting a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1288, Size: 1287`
this is in reference to `ArrayList<Formant> stored` in the first for loop. I dont understand why the capacity of the ArrayList is being set to 1287 rather than `dp.size`

Can anyone help with this? 
I've increased the max heap size to 10Gb
I've tried setting the initial capacity to 2048 (the max size of dp).
Relevant code is shown below:

```
public Formant[] analyzeBuffer(ArrayList<DataPoint> dp) {
    //declare variables
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    ArrayList<DataPoint> stored = new ArrayList<>(dp.size());
    Formant[] buffForm = new Formant[12];
    //f = new Formant(greatest);

    //control for infinit loop
    //while loop checks if datapoint is above threshhold, finds the largest number, and removes all datapoints within a given formant
    while (!(dp.isEmpty())) {

        //checks if data point is above threshold, if yes:  stores data point in new arraylist
        for (DataPoint td : dp) {
            if (td.returnFreq() > threshold) {
                stored.add(count1, td);
                count1++;

            }
            //checks if data point is the largest number
            if (td.returnFreq() > greatest) {
                greatest = td.returnFreq();
                f = new Formant(greatest);
            }
        }
        //only removes data points that are formants
        //removes all data points within a given formant
        if (f.isFormant) {
            buffForm[count2] = f;
            count2++;
            for (int k = 0; k < stored.size(); k++) {
                if (stored.get(k).returnFreq() <= (f.determineFormant() + 150) && stored.get(k).returnFreq() >= (f.determineFormant() - 150)) {
                    stored.remove(k);

                }
            }

        }
        //if freqeuncy is not formant remove all instances of that data point
        else{
            buffForm[count2] = f;
            count2++;
            for (int k = 0; k < stored.size(); k++) {
                if (stored.get(k).returnFreq() == f.freq) {
                    stored.remove(k);

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return buffForm;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An ArrayList's capacity is different than its size. Its size is "how many elements are in this," whereas the capacity is "how many elements can I put in before the ArrayList has to re-size its internal array?"

[`List#add(int idx, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) adds an element at the given index, but it requires that the List's *size* (not capacity) be large enough:

> [throws] `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index > size())`

Answer (score 1):

```
stored.remove(k);
```

You just shrank `stored`, so the larger indexes are no longer valid.

You need to make your loop run backwards, so that you never try to use an index that got shifted by a removal.